# Strange things happening when I override the getters and setters of my ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` model where I include a mobile phone number. The mobile phone number will be saved in the database in international format. Because users are often not aware of this and do not like international formats, I changed the getter and setters so that the user is able to enter numbers in local format and they get the local format displayed, if there is no international prefix.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def mobile=(number)
    # Strip whitespace, dashes and slashes first
    [" ", "-", "/", "\\"].each do |particle|
      number.gsub!(particle, "")
    end

    # Check if there is leading 00, this indicates a
    # country code.
    number.gsub!(/^00/,"+")

    # Check if there is only one leading zero. If there is,
    # treat as German number
    number.gsub!(/^0/,"+49")

    # Now write to attribute. Validate later.
    puts "Writing: #{number}"
    write_attribute(:mobile, number)
  end

  def mobile
    number = read_attribute(:mobile)
    puts "Reading: #{number}"

    # If this is a German number, display as local number.
    number.gsub!(/\+49/,"0")

    number
  end
end
```

Now, it seems that this does not work quite as expected. This is my `rails console` session:

```
> u = User.new(:mobile => "0163 12345")
Writing: +4916312345
 => #<User id: nil, mobile: "+4916312345", ...>
```

This worked as expected. So, lets check the getter:

```
> u.mobile
Reading: +4916312345
 => "016312345"
```

Looks good. But better check it again:

```
> u.mobile
Reading: 016312345
 => "016312345"
```

WTF? My attribute changed. Is this limited to the getter function?

```
> u
 => #<User id: nil, mobile: "016312345", ...>
```

No. It sets the attribute even in the database model.

If I access the attribute twice, the attribute changes. I did not access `write_attribute`. Why does my attribute change?

Comment: Why are you doing this here and not in a validator, or a `before_save` filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this simplified example:

```
class User
  def initialize
    @attributes = { :mobile => "+4916312345" }
  end
  def read_attribute name
    @attributes[name]
  end
end
```

Notice that `read_attribute` returns the value of the attribute, not a *copy* of the value.

Now:

```
user = User.new
mobile = user.read_attribute :mobile
=> "+4916312345"
mobile.gsub!(/\+49/,"0")
=> "016312345"
mobile = user.read_attribute :mobile
=> "016312345"   # because we modified it in place with gsub!
```

All you need to do is use `gsub` instead of `gsub!` in your getter, and since you'll never replace `+49` more than once in the same string, you might as well just use `sub`.

```
def mobile
  number = read_attribute(:mobile)
  puts "Reading: #{number}"

  # If this is a German number, display as local number.
  number.sub(/\+49/,"0")
end
```